# Counting items from a drop down list

Tags: microsoft-excel, google-spreadsheets

I’m trying to make an exercise spreadsheet to count sets for a certain muscle group.

I organized movements into muscle groups.

[image: photo]

Then, I wanted an user-facing input section like this, where the user could use a drop down menu, enter an exercise, and the number of sets.

[image: photo]

Then, a statistics page would list “Chest: 3, Front Delts: 2, Back: 2” for example.

I tried using COUNTIF and MATCH but didn’t get anything usable.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

My method needs to add an "Auxiliary column" to get the title for each exercise item.
On my sample, the formula is `=IFERROR(INDEX(A$1:D$1,SUMPRODUCT(($A$2:$D$6=A11)*(COLUMN($A$1:$D$1)))),"")`.

[image]

Then I enter the formula in Cell A7 and fill to the right, the formula is `=IF(SUMPRODUCT(($C11:$C16=A$1)*($B11:$B16))=0,"",A1&":"&SUMPRODUCT(($C11:$C16=A$1)*($B11:$B16)))`.

[image]

Please note, the range of "$C11:$C16" is not stationary, you may use a larger range to let users choose the exercise item.

[image]